# Trying different protein powders for taste

Tags: nutrition, protein

I'd like to try different flavours of protein powders to see which one better suits my taste. However, almost all those sold in shops/online weigh at least 500g, often 1kg or more. Which makes it impossible to try more than 2 or 3 without spending a lot of money and possibly wasting a lot of powder.

How do people actually do it in practice? Do they just try their luck and hope they'll like it? Are there sample bags of miscellaneous flavors with a small amount of each that can be bought? Or do shops offer small amounts for you to try?

(I didn't see any of that at Holland & Barrett, and I didn't go to any gyms, either, in case that's relevant.)

Comment: try your luck. ask friends. ive seen at Sprouts, small individual protein packets before, but only for a few specific brands. online ratings and reviews.

Comment: Voting to close as it's about nutrition and not physical fitness. Though assuming you're UK based, I believe MyProtein and BulkPowders, both UK based, do sell small sample packets of various flavours of their protein powder

Comment: Sorry for misreading the topic, and thanks for the recommendation, indeed searching for "whey protein **sample**" or similar gives better results.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I've seen, the try-your-luck approach is popular, as are the closely-related ask-your-friends and read-some-reviews approaches.  I haven't seen small samples of protein powder.

Answer (score 3):

~~A Workaround~~

Find someone who you know will want whatever you don’t use. Protein powder has a nice long shelf life, so it doesn’t hurt to keep extra in stock. Some people also like to have some variety to break up the norm. Regardless, talk with this person and agree on a price that they will buy the powder off of you.

Buy a few flavors and see which ones you like. Sell the ones you don’t.

... alternatively, just find a friend (or two, or three) Who work out and ask if you can try some of what they have.